# Access multidimensional $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

From an ajax call i'm sending some data like

```
rows[tr1][rowDesc]:ccccc
rows[tr1][rowTaxable]:77777
rows[tr1][rowVAT]:22% 
rows[tr1][rowTAX]:17110.94
rows[tr1][rowTOTAL]:94887.94
rows[tr2][rowDesc]:ddddd
rows[tr2][rowTaxable]:55555
rows[tr2][rowVAT]:22% 
rows[tr2][rowTAX]:12222.1
rows[tr2][rowTOTAL]:67777.1
```

which gives with `print_r($_POST['rows']);` the following multidimensional array

```
Array 
( 
[tr1] => Array
            ( 
              [rowDesc] => ccccc 
              [rowTaxable] => 77777 
              [rowVAT] => 22% 
              [rowTAX] => 17110.94 
              [rowTOTAL] => 94887.94 
            ) 
[tr2] => Array 
            ( 
              [rowDesc] => ddddd 
              [rowTaxable] => 55555
              [rowVAT] => 22% 
              [rowTAX] => 12222.1 
              [rowTOTAL] => 67777.1 
             )
 )
```

I've tried to access the subarrays with a foreach loop, which gives me only the first one. So, how to access the various "tr1,tr2,tr3,ecc..." values and keys?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: How did you tried to loop through the array? Show your code.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to access the sub arrays because you can't access the sub arrays without first accessing the parent array in some way

Comment: @aldrin27 output should be that i can loop through the key and values of the subarrays. E.g.:  `foreach($_POST['tr$i'] as $key => $value){//do something}`. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Memor-X I still haven't access to the subarrays, that's the point.

Comment: @Someone33 *"I've tried to access the subarrays with a foreach loop, which gives me only the first one"* this tells me you can access the first sub array. anyway with the code you commented `$value` is now the sub array so you should be able to do a second for loop with something like `foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue)`

Comment: @Memor-X first subarray is accessed with `foreach($_POST['rows'] as $row){return $row;} ` which gives `Array ( [rowDesc] => ccccc [rowTaxable] => 77777 [rowVAT] => 22% [rowTAX] => 17110.94 [rowTOTAL] => 94887.94 )`

Comment: If you want to access sub-array `$_POST['rows' ]['tr1'][rwDesc'];` or use foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
foreach($_POST['rows'] as $key => $value){

    if(is_array($value)){

       foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue){

          echo $subkey;
          echo $subvalue;

       }

    }else{

      echo $key;
      echo $value;

    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me as result only the first $key - $value pair of the first subarray: _rowDesc_  _ccccc_

Comment: Hmm...that doesn't make sense

Comment: Yep, i know. That's why i'm stucked. It works with 0,1,2,3 ecc...subarrays, but not with "tr1","tr2","tr3", ecc...

Comment: It works though http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5402f23516cc4ebee88faded99919935a06f139

Comment: @Someone33 It's also good to check if the value of the first array is an array first before looping through the subset or else it will throw an error.

Comment: Yep, sorry. As my $_Post is send to a function inside a class i always used "return" instead of "echo". I tried this for two hours, got always the code before my eyes but i didn't think of "echo" :-((.

Comment: It's always an array because this data comes from table rows inside a form. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: But now i don't know which answer to vote because they are both the right one.

Comment: Haha...go with your heart ;)

Comment: Though my answer extends your current use a bit, it may become helpful down the road for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to access subarrays:

```
foreach($_POST['rows'] as $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        echo $key . " : " . $value . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
rowDesc : ccccc rowTaxable : 77777 rowVAT : 22% rowTAX : 17110.94 rowTOTAL : 94887.94
rowDesc : ddddd rowTaxable : 77777 rowVAT : 22% rowTAX : 12222.1 rowTOTAL : 67777.1
```

Comment: Nope :-(. I get only the first $key - $value pair of the first subarray.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, i used "return" instead of "echo". With return it returns only the first pair. So your code seems to work. I tried this for 2 hours :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers! :)

Comment: But now i don't know which answer to vote because they are both the right one.

Comment: @Someone33 Like VIDesignz said, go with your heart. :)